# How to pass marquee beneath the fixed navbar without interrupting the navbar content

Tags: jquery, html, css, marquee

I have created a fixed header and also my page contains a jquery marquee for news feeds but the difference b/w both is that the marquee is scrollable. Now the problem arises here when I scroll the page and the marquee goes from the upside of the fixed header. Please Help me if You got my problem.

I tried to bound this code under the div tag but it didn't help me.
please try and resolve my problem and help me. try a fixed header and make this code scrollable beneath fixed menu, please.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .card1 {
            justify-content: center;
            width: 85%;
            left: 400px;
            box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            height: 200px;
            margin: auto;
            background-color: aliceblue;
            text-align: center;
            font: normal 18px 'Cookie', cursive;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="card1">
        <center style="font-family: cursive; color:red;">
            <h3>Information Counter</h3>
        </center>


        <div align="center" class>
            <div id="marquee0" align="center">
                <script src="https://ajax.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/scripts/2448a7bd/cloudflare-static/rocket-loader.min.js" data-cf-nonce="f1a80adeaa41ba9339409f79-"></script>
                <p>
                    <marquee behavior="alternate" onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();" scrollamount="5" style="text-decoration:none;"><?php $i = 1; 

$custom_query = new WP_Query('cat=8'); 
while($custom_query->have_posts() && $i < 3) : $custom_query->the_post(); ?>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" target=_blank><b>
                                <font size="4"><?php the_title(); ?></font>
                            </b></a> ||
                        <?php $i++; endwhile; ?>
                        <?php wp_reset_postdata();?>
                    </marquee>
                </p>

            </div>
            <div id="marquee0" align="center">
                <script src="https://ajax.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/scripts/2448a7bd/cloudflare-static/rocket-loader.min.js" data-cf-nonce="f1a80adeaa41ba9339409f79-"></script>
                <marquee behavior="alternate" onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();" scrollamount="10">
                    <?php $i = 1; 

$custom_query = new WP_Query('cat=7');
while($custom_query->have_posts() && $i < 4) : $custom_query->the_post(); ?>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" target=_blank><b>
                            <font size="3"><?php the_title(); ?></font>
                        </b></a> ||
                    <?php $i++; endwhile; ?>
                    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                </marquee>
            </div>
            <div id="marquee0" align="center">``
                <script src="https://ajax.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/scripts/2448a7bd/cloudflare-static/rocket-loader.min.js" data-cf-nonce="f1a80adeaa41ba9339409f79-"></script>
                <marquee behavior="alternate" onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();" scrollamount="7">
                    <?php $i = 1; 
$custom_query = new WP_Query('cat=6');
while($custom_query->have_posts() && $i < 4) : $custom_query->the_post(); ?>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" target=_blank><b>
                            <font size="3"><?php the_title(); ?></font>
                        </b></a> ||
                    <?php $i++; endwhile; ?>
                    <?php wp_reset_postdata();?>
                </marquee>
            </div>
            <div id="marquee0" align="center">
                <script src="https://ajax.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/scripts/2448a7bd/cloudflare-static/rocket-loader.min.js" data-cf-nonce="f1a80adeaa41ba9339409f79-"></script>
                <marquee behavior="alternate" onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();" scrollamount="12">
                    <?php $i = 1; $custom_query = new WP_Query('cat=9'); while($custom_query->have_posts() && $i < 4) : $custom_query->the_post(); ?>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" target=_blank><b>
                            <font size="3"><?php the_title(); ?></font>
                        </b></a> ||<?php $i++; endwhile; ?>
                    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?> </marquee>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your code.

Firstly, you don't need to add the jquery link each time you wish to use it for something, adding it once will make it available to any use of it, it should also be added in the `head` or at the bottom of the `body`.

Secondly, `element` IDs are meant to be unique, don't use the same ID for multiple elements, Use classes to group similar elements. [Info on classes](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_classes.asp)

Thirdly, you have added style tags for the markup (if that was just for this question ignore this part) you are better off using CSS and you also use style markup within elements `<center style="font-family: cursive; color:red;">` have your styling in different places will make it harder for you to maintain and update it.

..and Finally

here is an update of your code that fixes the issues outlined above, it uses `NOWDOC` to `echo` out each post. [Info](https://joshtronic.com/2013/11/11/outputting-a-string-with-here-document-syntax/)

````php
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/scripts/2448a7bd/cloudflare-static/rocket-loader.min.js" data-cf-nonce="f1a80adeaa41ba9339409f79-"></script>
    <style>
        .card1 {
            justify-content: center;
            width: 85%;
            left: 400px;
            box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            height: 200px;
            margin: auto;
            background-color: aliceblue;
            text-align: center;
            font: normal 18px 'Cookie', cursive;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="card1">

        <center style="font-family: cursive; color:red;">
            <h3>Information Counter</h3>
        </center>

        <div align="center" class>
            <div id="marquee0" align="center">
                <marquee behavior="alternate" onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();" scrollamount="5" style="text-decoration:none;">
                <?php $i = 1; 
                    $custom_query = new WP_Query('cat=8'); 
                    while($custom_query->have_posts() && $i < 3) : $custom_query->the_post(); 

                        echo <<<DOC
                            <a href="{$custom_query->the_permalink()}" target=_blank><b><font size="4">$custom_query->the_title()</font></b></a> ||
                            $i++;
DOC;
                    endwhile;
                    wp_reset_postdata();
                    ?>
                </marquee>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>```
````

Now with this code see if the issue persists and if it does please update the question.

Comment: Still facing the error marquee and the fixed menu is overlapping. see the proof image- https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hHw922XsUVvVuXWyKXuLD9E06VWytEsm/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You are trying to use PHP on a HTML file, create a PHP file and copy the header.html contents to it. https://www.upwork.com/hiring/development/php-vs-html/